# VBA Text Array - Scan two columns for array string match rather than one

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code which is designed to scan Columns F & G for occurrences of words found in an array, the array containing text found in Column J. If it finds occurrences in either Column F or Column G, it will copy and paste the terms into the corresponding columns.

Column J contains free text from a field in SAP. The field is free text so it could be "Kerry John Pub Expenses" or "CATS O/H Kerry John", or even "CATS John Kerry O/H". There is no data entry standard for this field; this is what makes this task difficult .

Column F and Column G contains first names and last names. The code makes an assumption, if it finds an entry in column F or G that matches an entry in the txt array, it will copy and paste that entry.

During testing, the code proved not sufficient to match the outcomes which I was looking for, and the solution to this problem would be to match text in Columns F and G concurrently for two matching words rather than doing them in separate intervals.

I would like some suggestions as to how this code could be re-written to achieve this result.

**Example of successful code run**

Here we have 4 rows of data, John Citizen is located in Row 3, therefore the blank cells in Columns F and G, Row 2 can be populated with his first and last name.

[image]

[image]

**The problem**

[image]

Because I have two rows that contain Kerry Citizen and John Kerry, the row is populated with Kerry Kerry as a result, where the entry should be "John" in Column F and  "Kerry" in Column G

[image]

Code starts here

```
Sub arraycolumnmatch()
Dim txtArray As Variant, T As Variant
Dim I As Long, J As Long

For I = 2 To Range("E50000").End(xlUp).row
    typ = Range("F" & I).Value
    If typ = "" Then
        txt = Range("J" & I).Value
        txtArray = Split(txt, " ")

        For Each T In txtArray
            For J = 2 To Range("F50000").End(xlUp).row
                If Range("F" & J).Value = T Then
                    match_txt = T
                    Range("F" & I).Value = match_txt
                End If
            Next J
        Next T

        For Each T In txtArray
            For J = 2 To Range("G50000").End(xlUp).row
                If Range("G" & J).Value = T Then
                    match_txt = T
                    Range("G" & I).Value = match_txt
                End If
            Next J
        Next T
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Just for future reference, it also helps when you use _meaningful_ variable names. Something like `i` is fine if it's just being used as a counter in a loop, but using variables like `firstName`, `lastName`, `postingDate` make the code so much easier to follow for other people that may be reading it and don't understand the initial context in which the code was written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code greatly, and make it work, like this:

```
    typ = Range("F" & I).Value
    If typ = "" Then
        txt = Range("J" & I).Value

        matchFound = False
        For J = 2 To Range("G50000").End(xlUp).Row
            If InStr(txt, Range("F" & J).Value) <> 0 _
                And InStr(txt, Range("G" & J).Value)  _
                And Not (IsEmpty(Range("F" & J).Value)) _
                And Not (IsEmpty(Range("G" & J).Value)) Then

                'Both names match. Copy them.
                Range("F" & I).Value = Range("F" & J).Value
                Range("G" & I).Value = Range("G" & J).Value
                matchFound = True
                Exit For ' look no further.
            End If
        Next J

        If Not matchFound Then MsgBox "No match found for: " & txt

    End If
```

Tested, works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Code below runs for every first name on the list but only adds the name if both names match.

```
    Sub arraycolumnmatch()
    Dim txtArray As Variant, t As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

    For I = 2 To Range("G50000").End(xlUp).Row
        typ = Range("F" & I).Value
        If typ = "" And Not Range("J" & I).Value = Empty Then
            txt = Range("J" & I).Value
            txtArray = Split(txt, " ")

            For Each word In txtArray
                If Not word = "" Then
                    Set findtext = Range("F:F").Find _
                    (what:=(word), LookIn:=xlValues)
                    stoploop = False
                    loopcnt = 0

                    Do While Not findtext Is Nothing And stoploop = False And loopcnt < 21
                        loopcnt = loopcnt + 1
                        If InStr(txt, Range("F" & findtext.Row).Value) <> 0 _
                            And InStr(txt, Range("G" & findtext.Row).Value) Then
                            'Both names match. Copy them.
                            Range("F" & I).Value = Range("F" & findtext.Row).Value
                            Range("G" & I).Value = Range("G" & findtext.Row).Value
                            stoploop = True
                            Exit For ' look no further.
                        Else
                            Set findtext = Range("F" & findtext.Row & ":F" & 50000).Find _
                            (what:=(word), LookIn:=xlValues)
                        End If
                    Loop
                End If
            Next word

                If Not stoploop Then MsgBox "No match found for: " & txt

        End If
    Next I
    End Sub
```

Edit: Did an integration of @Jean InStr and a Find in Range which would allow for less loop time and a double match find.

Comment: Miguel, this code doesn't resolve my issue, it works similar to mine but with more loops, and I still get one match.  I am playing around with Jeans idea above.  The only issue with this approach is whilst instr is a good boolean check, it doesn't fetch the matching strings

Comment: Hi @PootyToot, do you want to have a try at the re-written code, it should be faster and more accurate. Regards Miguel.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to stick with my original syntax, answer is below.  Not the most efficient way of reaching the result, but it works

```
    Sub arraycolumnmatch()
    Dim txtArray As Variant, T As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

    For I = 2 To Range("E50000").End(xlUp).row
        typ = Range("F" & I).Value
    If typ = "" Then
        txt = Range("J" & I).Value
        txtArray = Split(txt, " ")

        For Each T In txtArray
            For J = 2 To Range("G50000").End(xlUp).row
                If Range("G" & J).Value = T Then
                    match_txt = T
                    Range("G" & I).Value = match_txt
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next J
        Next T

        For Each T In txtArray
            For J = 2 To Range("F50000").End(xlUp).row
                If Range("F" & J).Value = T Then
                       match_txt = T
                       If Not Range("G" & I).Value = T Then
                          Range("F" & I).Value = match_txt
                          Exit For
                       End If
                End If
            Next J
        Next T
   End If
Next I
```